# libgdx: How to stop touchUp event?

Tags: libgdx

As I can see from [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d#event-system) article you can easily use "stop" method to stop event propagation, but this doesn't work for "touchUp/touchDown" event (event isn't stopped). I have also tested it for "mousemove" event and found that it works for it. Why? How can i stop "touchUp/touchDown" event?

PS: libgdx version: 1.2.0,
    I'm using scene2d.

Answer (score 0):

From [github wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling#inputmultiplexer):

> The `InputMultiplexer` will hand any new events to the first `InputProcessor` that was added to it. **If that processor returns false from the method invoked to handle the event, this indicates the event was not handled and the multiplexer will hand the event to the next processor in the chain**. Through this mechanism, the `MyUiInputProcessor` can handle any events that fall inside one of its widgets and pass on any other events to the `MyGameInputProcessor`.

**TL;DR:** Return `true` from your handle function if you want to stop it from propagation.

Also, what version of LibGDX are you using? I use `1.2.0` and the `touchUp()` method returns a `boolean`, unline that in the tutaril from your question.

Comment: sory, forgot to write about that. i'm using scene 2d so i have the only inputProcessor that is called stage. As i can see from source the stage code is written in such was that stoping doesn't work on touchUp event. Of cource i can owerride stage with my custom logic, so stopping will work, but it is hack i think.

Comment: also, about your answer: as i know scene2d doesn't creates separate inputProcessor for each Actor.addListener call. They all are handled by 1 inputProcessor (Stage). Am i right?

Comment: Hi Vlad, can you explain a bit what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean stop?

Comment: hi. i have a button and some parent actor. I'm adding touchUp listeners to both of them. in the button's touchUp listener i'm calling Event.stop method (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Event.html#stop--). but both listeners are called. When i'm using 'mouseMoved' event listeners for example stop method works as expected (moving mouse over button doesn't invokes parent's listener).

Comment: Aloso I have read source a bit and i see that this different behavior of touchUp and mouseMove events are processed differently in Stage Class (mouseMoved uses fire method on the target element https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.java#L373 and touchUp doesn't).